# What does it mean when variables start with a dot/period in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, variables

Some of the parameters in this call for example:

```
 ConnectToDatabase(oCustomPropReader.ConnectionType, .ConnectString, _
           oCustomPropReader.SystemMdb, .UserName, .Password)
```

Why do UsernName, Password, and ConnectString have dots before them? Thanks!

Comment: I have never liked the [`With`-statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx). Strange code without added value.

Comment: either it is in a `WITH.. END WITH` block or in a `USING..END USING` block

Comment: @Nadeem_MK - it isn't `Using` you can't access properties like that from within a 'Using' block

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are properties (or methods) of an object declared as `With` (See [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) for more info.)

Consider the following:

```
 Dim obj As New Object
 obj.Username = "foo"
 obj.Password = "bar"
```

this is the same as the following:

```
 Dim obj As New Object
 With obj
       .Username = "foo"
       .Password = "bar"
 End With
```

They can reduce the amount of characters you have to type if you are reading or writing a lot of properties within the same object.

It can also improve readability if you have a long object name.

Note that that code you are looking at may have the `With` and `End With` off the currently viewable page so it is not obvious what these properties refer to.

Comment: For long object names, there are much better ways to improve readability.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas - without any example I'm not sure your comment is at all useful.

Comment: Just set a temporary reference: Dim shortName = Foo.Bar.SomeIncrediblyLongName and then use 'shorName' within that scope. This is much clearer than using a 'With' block.